# 20.04 GNOME Desktop would not load after login

Tags: 20.04, gnome, gdm

Sometimes my desktop would be stuck loading after I log in. I'd get an entirely purple screen with a functional mouse pointer but nothing else. Usually the rest of the desktop would load in normally after a few seconds, but about once every 5-10 boots it would get stuck for several minutes until I switch to a tty and reboot. This has been happening for several months, but it seems to have gotten more frequent lately.

Here is some output from `systemctl status gdm`:

```
Aug 09 04:04:05 solitude gdm-password][1665]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user tyler by (uid=0)
Aug 09 04:04:06 solitude gdm-password][1665]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Aug 09 04:04:06 solitude gdm3[1169]: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-password
Aug 09 04:04:06 solitude gdm3[1169]: Tried to look up non-existent conversation gdm-password
Aug 09 04:04:06 solitude gdm3[1169]: GdmSession: Tried to start session of nonexistent conversation gdm-password
```

It seems that the lines about "non-existent conversation gdm-password" would show up every time it happens. I have tried installing haveged but it doesn't seem to fix the problem. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from 18.04). Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Possibly disk on its way out

Comment: @cup That should be unlikely though since my SSD is only less than 4 years old without much heavy use.

Comment: A drive can go bad the day you get it so it could be the drive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work but you can try running 'dpkg' by going to recovery menu during boot. It did help me to fix my broken packages during installation.
But problem could be in the disk as said by cup and David in the comments.

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't seem to have done anything. It just said "finished" immediately without any other output. Thanks for the tip though.